# Laravel Many To Many Relationship Check with intermediate table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

i'm new here and very much hope i'm not asking a duplicate question.

I am completely new to coding and jumped right into Laravel, but now running into an issue that i'm not quite finding an answer for.

I have the following Model setup:

**User.php**

```
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_roles')->as('roles')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Role.php**

Has a table column 'name'

```
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_roles');
    }
```

**UserRole.php**

Intermediate table with table columns 'user_id and 'role_id'

The issue that i'm facing is that i want to create a role check on the user, and i am guessing that creating a middleware will be the way to go. But when i want to check if a user has a role with the following code:

```
if (Auth::user()->roles->name == 'manager')
    {
        // do something here
    }
    else {
        // do something else here
    }
```

I get an error stating that 'name' does not exist on this collection instance.

I figured out that i can loop over the roles a user has and display them with:

```
$user = User::find(1);
foreach($user->roles as $role)
{
print $role->name;
}
```

But i'm completely clueless as to why the role check isn't working.

Comment: Like that ? `Auth::user()->roles()->where('name', 'manager')->first();`

Comment: This way seems to work as well, but i'm not quite sure why it is ->roles() instead of ->roles and the ->first() addition

Comment: When you use a function it returns QueryBuilder not a Collection. So instead of getting everything and sorting it sorts in query and retrieves first instance.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense, ty for explaining :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auth::user()->roles` is a collection of roles, an instance of [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#introduction). So for that check, you might want to do something like:

```php
if (Auth::user()->roles->contains('name', 'manager') {
    // do something here
} else {
    // do something else here
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, ty ! I hadn't quite seen the contains function.

Answer (score 1):

as Auth::user()->roles returns collection of all roles so you can not apply "==" operator directly